# Automate multiple script files .sql and export result to excel SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm trying to execute multiple SQL files and export the results to Excel files.
Until now, i used the «For each lood container» with the «Execute SQL task» and it's running well...
I think i should use «For each lood container» and «Data flow task», but i can't use multiple exports in it.
Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0):

For multiple exports, 
you can use a variable with expression for your excel file name. Increment it for each loop and use in your FileSystem Task to create the file.

Comment: for now i have the «for each loop container» and a «Data Flow Task» in it. In the data flow, i used a «OLE DB source» to specify the query...and i used in «data access mode» a «SQL command from variable»...In the variable name i used the variable «FilesName»...and i have an error when i click on preview «An OLE DB error occured...Description: Command text was not set for the command objetct»...

Comment: If you use a sql command from variable that means you've a variable with a query ...
if you prefer to test, add a variable with expression (DT_WSTR,30)GetDate() +".xlsx" and add the variable to the create excel file task in the case 'DestinationVariable' 'User::FileName'
For each loop you'll get a different excel file with the datetime as name